# TypeError: MessageActionRow is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Im using discord V13 and im getting this error.
(If you prefer you can look at the code in this link: https://sourceb.in/8w8wKS1Wmy)

Main file:

```js
// main.js

const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

The command file:

```js
// command 

const {
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton
} = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'commands',
    permissions: [],
    description: "this sends help!",
    aliases: ['cmd', 'cmdinfo', 'commandsinfo'],
    execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord) {

            const utilbtn = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel('Primary')
                    .setStyle('PRIMAMRY'),
                    
                );

            const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('**Commands**')

            message.channel.send({
                embed: [newEmbed],
                component: [utilbtn]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
// the error 

const utilbtn = new MessageActionRow()
                ^           

TypeError: MessageActionRow is not a constructor
```

Comment: What exact version of discord.js are you using? You can find this in your package.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot imagine how this is not working, unless if you are using the wrong version, consider running:

```
npm i discord.js@13.1.0
```

I've tried running both:

```js
const { MessageActionRow } = require('discord.js');
// undefined
new MessageActionRow()
// MessageActionRow { type: 'ACTION_ROW', components: [] }
```

The commented lines are the response when running node in console. Maybe try checking package.json, should have a line like the following:

```json
"discord.js": "^13.1.0"
```